# Como alterar o valor de inputs subsequentes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em um formulário há N ocorrências de valores para um mesmo produto, para facilitar estou querendo aplicar o mesmo valor para os inputs subsequentes.

Por exemplo, utilizando a estrutura abaixo:

```
<input class="valor partida" type="text" name="novo_valor_partida-1" value="11,11" data-produto="0101000" data-id="1">

<input class="valor partida" type="text" name="novo_valor_partida-2" value="11,11" data-produto="0101000" data-id="2">

<input class="valor partida" type="text" name="novo_valor_partida-3" value="11,11" data-produto="0101000" data-id="3">
```

Ao efetuar a modificação do valor no input 1, o 2 e 3 também receberão o valor. Se o input 2 for alterado, somente o 3 recebe o valor e assim sucessivamente.

Como há N campos, utilizarei o atributo `data-produto` para selecionar os inputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('input').val(this.value);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abyy9qr8/

O [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) vai buscar todos os *proximos* siblings do elemento, neste caso com o seletor `input`.

Usei o evento `change` mas também podes usar o `keyup` e assim acontece no momento de escrita. Talvez queiras usar os dois para ter a certeza que funciona mesmo que o conteúdo tenha sido colocado por copy/paste.

Comment: Isso garante que os inputs serão analisados na mesma ordem que estão no html? Só curiosidade.

Comment: @Renan não tenho a certeza da ordem, mas os docs dizem _"Get all following siblings"_, por tanto siblings anteriores não serão incluídos.

Comment: Sergio, utilizando blur e uma versão mais antiga não obtenho o mesmo resultado. Estou utilizando, infelizmente, a versão 1.4.4 e o evento blur devido algumas verificações que farei no input.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade queres dizer que precisas de usar o evento `.blur()`? ou podes usar os dois? `$('input').on('change blur', function() {`

Comment: Posso usar os dois, porém acredito que a versão que estou utilizando não ajudará pois ocorre erro `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function` no método além de não aplicar o `nextAll`

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade ah, pois o `.on(` veio mais tarde :) muda para `.bind(`

Comment: @Sergio uma coisa que notei é que ele "trava" dependendo do nível do elemento. Por exemplo: Se o elemento estiver em uma `TR` diferente, não funciona. Exemplo do HTML que estou utilizando: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c05nakev)

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade no teu exemplo na pergunta os inputs são _siblings_ daí a solução que indiquei na resposta. Se não forem, e quiseres dar o mesmo valor tens de fazer de outra maneira, por exemplo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/4k3x49sL/1/ Por isso é que é importante a pergunta ter o maior detalhe possivel para a resposta ser certeira e ajudar.

Comment: Entendi, @Sergio.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo em jQuery.

- Seleciono todos os inputs que o `data-produto` seja `0101000`
- Adiciono a todos eles um listen para os eventos `change` e `keyup`
- Salvo o valor do input que chamou o evento
- Atribuo o novo valor para todos os inputs

```js
var $todosInputs = $('input[data-produto=\'0101000\']');
$todosInputs.on('change keyup', function() {
  $(this).nextAll($todosInputs).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="valor partida" type="text" name="novo_valor_partida-1" value="11,11" data-produto="0101000" data-id="1">
<input class="valor partida" type="text" name="novo_valor_partida-2" value="11,11" data-produto="0101000" data-id="2">
<input class="valor partida" type="text" name="novo_valor_partida-3" value="11,11" data-produto="0101000" data-id="3">
```

Comment: Porém se eu editar o segundo elemento, o primeiro também é afetado.

Comment: Corrigido @MarcelodeAndrade